# Trying to use rowspan on <td> html table on a foreach, not working

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to use a rowspan on a `<td>` html table on a foreach, but it's not working.

It adds columns to the right of the checkout. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oc9vabvx/62/).

```
<?php
$rowspan = 1;
foreach ($conn->query($sqltodos) as $rowdfpq_conteudo) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $contarow++;
}
?>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oc9vabvx/62/

Comment: What kind of foreach? If you are looping over results from php it would help if you could post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should *omit* those `TD` elements in next rows that are occupied by the rowspanned cell.